# Why isn't .hover() working with Animate.css?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-hover, animate.css, megamenu

I'm creating a mega menu. Everything is working great except when the mouse hovers over the menu itself -- after it appears with the animation -- the menu then hides.

This only happens when the animate.css classes "animated" and "bounceIn" are in the code. When they're removed, and just the class "show" is added, the menu doesn't hide when it's hovered and works correctly.

Is there a special twist to using animate.css with .hover()?

HTML

```
<div class="nav">
    <ul>
        <li class="wsite-nav-1">Home</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="mega-menu">
          <div class="menu-1 menu">Mega Menu</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.menu {
  border:1px solid #004698;
  padding:2em;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  display:none;
}
.menu.show {
  display:block;
}
```

jQuery

```
  // Mega Menu
  $('.menu-1, .wsite-nav-1').hover(function() {
    $('.menu-1.menu').addClass('show animated bounceIn');
  },function() {
    $('.menu-1.menu').removeClass('show animated bounceIn');
  });
```

Comment: you forgot to close class with `"` `<li class="wsite-nav-1>Home</li>` and `</ul` with `>`

Comment: Oops! It's an early morning. All closed, but the issue remains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can use only css** as below and move `.mega-menu` inside `li`

```css
.menu {
  border:1px solid #004698;
  padding:2em;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  display:none;
}

.wsite-nav-1:hover .menu{
    display:block;
    -webkit-animation: bounceIn 1s;
    animation: bounceIn 1s;
}
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.7.0/animate.css">
<div class="nav">
    <ul>
        <li class="wsite-nav-1">Home
          <div class="mega-menu">
            <div class="menu-1 menu">Mega Menu</div>
          </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: No. The animation works just fine. The problem is when I move the mouse from the parent menu item in the navigation to the menu, the menu then hides when it shouldn't.

Comment: ok let me check it.... but with my code I think it does not happened .. am I right?